# Unable to delete some lists

Tags: delete-list

I'm trying to delete 7 old no more used lists from a `Web`. In the list settings there is no delete option. Trying to delete it using SharePoint Designer, PowerShell and SharePoint Manager I get the error "This List can't be deleted".

How can I delete them?

Some info on the farm:
The OnPremise farm has been built by my predecessor, I migrated it to 2013 and last year to 2016. I don't know if it started from 2007 or 2010, but I see that the main default.aspx is dated 27.05.2010.

Edit:
Of course, I'm not talking about syste libraries. These have been created by my predecessor.

Comment: Which names have these lists or document libraries? Aren'T they system based?

Comment: I added a comment

Comment: no matter you find solution by McShea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag on a list called `AllowDeletion`. If it's set to false, you will get this error when trying to delete. You need to change that flag to true.

Unfortunately, this flag is not exposed through the list settings page, or SharePoint Designer. There used to be a tool called SharePoint Manager on codeplex that would allow you to set this, but it doesn't look like there is a version for SharePoint 2016.

You can do it through Powershell:

```
#Load SharePoint PowerShell Snapin
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://foo.com/website"

$List = $Web.Lists["LibraryName"] 
$List.AllowDeletion = $TRUE 
$List.Update() 
$List.Delete()
$Web.Dispose()
```

Ref: [Fixing the AllowDeletion flag on a SharePoint list or library](https://sharepointduffbert.com/2016/04/05/fixing-the-allowdeletion-flag-on-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/)

Comment: As mentioned in the question I already know SharePoint Manager and it works fine also on 2016. Didn't know about the flag, the lists had it on false, by changing them on true I have been able to remove the lists. Thanks.